# Need a help Local.name(.) xquery function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery-sql

can any one tell me how Local.name(.) xquery function works. regarding sql construction problem i post a question in a forum and they give me answer. where Local.name(.) xquery function is used but syntax is not clear to me very well.

```
;with cte as
(
select x.i.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(MAX)') as colname
,x.i.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as data
from @x.nodes('/Record/DELETED/*') as x(i))
```

what is the meaning of this line x.i.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(MAX)') as colname why 'local-name(.)' what is local-name (.) what does it mean. again x.i.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as data please explain the two line in detail. i am not advance user. thanks a lot.

please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`local-name(.)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190650.aspx) will give you the node name of the current node. If you used local-name(..) you would get the node name of the parent node.

`x.i.value('.','nvarchar(max)')` will give you the content of the the current node.

`@x.nodes('/Record/DELETED/*')` gives you all nodes in `/Record/Deleted`.

So your query will give you a name/value list of all nodes in `/Record/Deleted`.